# How to convert <a href="http://xy.com">XY</a> to [http://xy.com XY]?

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

Just for editing Wiki's..

So i have this input [from a larget text]:

```
TEXT TEXT BLA-BLA RANDOMSTRINGS BLA-BLA
TEXT TEXT BLA-BLA RANDOMSTRINGS BLA-BLA
TEXT TEXT <a href="http://xy.com">XY</a> RANDOMSTRINGS BLA-BLA
TEXT TEXT BLA-BLA RANDOMSTRINGS BLA-BLA
TEXT TEXT BLA-BLA RANDOMSTRINGS BLA-BLA
```

and i want this output:

```
TEXT TEXT BLA-BLA RANDOMSTRINGS BLA-BLA
TEXT TEXT BLA-BLA RANDOMSTRINGS BLA-BLA
TEXT TEXT [http://xy.com XY] RANDOMSTRINGS BLA-BLA
TEXT TEXT BLA-BLA RANDOMSTRINGS BLA-BLA
TEXT TEXT BLA-BLA RANDOMSTRINGS BLA-BLA
```

"http://xy.com" could be e.g.: "https://xy.com" or "http://www.xy.com" or "https://www.xy.com", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without attempting to detect troublesome input (e.g. link or text containing `[]`), just capture everything between the `"…"` and between `>…</a>`:

```
sed -e 's!<a  *href *= *"\([^"]*\)" *>\([^<>]*\)</[Aa]>![\1 \2]!g'
```

Comment: who are you? some kind of god? :D THANK YOU!